# How do I remove delay between ringtones

Tags: ringtone

My new Droid Razr, and Razr Maxx phones put a small delay in between each ring.  Some of the factory ringtones are designed to be a continous loop.  for example "medieval jaunt", "romancing the tone", and "Crayon Rock" are designed to be looped with no delay, and sounds odd with the short delay in between rings.  I saw I similar question from about a year ago, which there seem to be no answer, but that was someone with the opposite issue, of wanting a delay.  Thanks!

Comment: So the problem is on the stock ringtones or on the ones that you try to use?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one specific ringtone picked out: take the audio file and loop it yourself (using something simple like [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)) and make it the length of a ring (typically 30 seconds).

Comment: And apart from from setting the length, trim the low or silent zones which could be at start or end of the ringtone. You can preview it in Audacity itself by looping the play before transferring the file to phone.

Comment: Or some `avconv` action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552901/how-to-merge-videos-by-avconv